# The document with the maximum value

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, max

I have many documents in Mongo of this structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5a05538b8a478e0794247416"),
    "mainId": "5e21b2ed28cf67567ed2bc30",
    "shortHeader": "John J.J.",
    "dateLastModification": ISODate("2019-09-25T07:49:34.732Z")
}
```

I need to get a document with a maximum date. I try to do it like this:

```
EntryMetaInfo mainMeta = metaService.getCollectionMetaByName("history");
Document searchQuery = new Document("mainId", "5e21b2ed28cf67567ed2bc30");
FindIterable<Document> oldDatas = mongoService.getDocuments(mainMeta, searchQuery);
Document modification = oldDatas.max(new Document("dateLastModification", null)).first();
```

But I get a MongoQueryException. How do I get a Document by the maximum date?

Comment: It sounds like you want an order? `find({ ... }).sort({"dateLastModification" : -1}).limit(1)` or similar?

Comment: @pandaadb There are several documents. They have the following DateLastModification: "2019-09-25T10: 49: 34.732Z", "2019-12-25T07: 49: 34.732Z", "2020-01-10T16: 49: 34.732Z". I need the document whose DateLastModification is the largest. Maybe you're right and I should streamline and take the first document from the list.

Comment: What is the largest date? Do you mean the oldest? That is a regular sort, why do you need to retrieve 3 documents where you will discard 2 of them immediately because the 3rd is the oldest anyway?

Comment: @pandaadb Your first comment helped me. Thank you

Comment: If the field is indexed and you care about performance you can also use Mongo's `max`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/